# Calling a function from another function JavaScript Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, function, api, google-maps

I am trying to add a function inside another function for the Google Maps API marker option. I am having problems with trying to add the function as an argument for the `addMarker({coordinates:{lat: 51.506, lng: -0.188}});` method.

I am trying to pass an argument into the function to be able to add it as a variable but it didn't work and I had to comment it.

```js
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

  function addMarker(props) {
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
      position:props.coordinates,
      map : map,
      icon: "img/logo2.png",
    });

    //contentInfo = function addInfoWindow(contentWindow) {
      let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<h3>Tower</h3>"
      });

      marker.addListener("click", function(){
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    //}
  }

  //Add Marker
  addMarker({coordinates:{lat: 51.506, lng: -0.188}});
  addMarker({coordinates:{lat: 51.497, lng: -0.129}});
  addMarker({coordinates:{lat: 51.515, lng: -0.098}});
}
```

---

### Edit

I actually want to be able to call this function:

```js
contentInfo = function addInfoWindow(contentWindow) {
  let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<h3>Tower</h3>"
  });

  marker.addListener("click", function(){
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

From within the function `addMarker`. Something like this:

```js
function addMarker({coordinates:{lat: 51.515, lng: -0.098}, infoWindow()});
```

But I can't find the proper logic or syntax to accomplish that.

Comment: So, you're saying that you want to add `infoWindow` as an argument to the `addMarker` function? Or are you asking how you can add a [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) as an argument to the `addMarker` function? Can you describe a little more what isn't working? I was able to run sample code from [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) docs and add markers with your code including the `addListener`s.

Comment: You can't call (execute) a function when assigned as an argument to another function as it appears you are hoping to do. In `function addMarker({coordinates:{lat: 51.515, lng: -0.098}, infoWindow()});` you reference `infoWindow` as a function but have not defined this as such - perhaps you meant `contentInfo` as that is the name assigned to your function.??

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear how the addition of a named function within the `addMarker` function was intended to be used - the code(commented) would do nothing but is valid. If the intention is to be able to call that named function by perhaps clicking on the marker there needs to be the means by which the function & marker are relatable - a custom property for the marker is the most obvious solution.

The following snippet will exhibit an error due to the lack of API key however the map will load and the functionality will work. The code below shows two methods of assigning functions to the marker - one by supplying a `callbacks` object within the existing `props` argument and the other, more akin to what you were trying to do, is supplied directly as a custom property of the marker.

```js
function initMap() {
  const latlng=new google.maps.LatLng( 51.512957, -0.133707 );
  const options = {
    zoom: 12,
    center:latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  const map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );
  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth:300});




  const dragendcallback=function(e){
    console.log('"dragend" event @%s,%s', e.latLng.lat().toFixed(3), e.latLng.lng().toFixed(3) );
    // call the function assigned as a property of the marker
    this.banana.call()
  };
  const clickcallback=function(e){
    with(infowindow){
      setContent(this.content);
      setPosition(e.latLng);
      open(map,this);
    }
    console.log('"click" event @%s,%s',e.latLng.lat(),e.latLng.lng());
  };
  const funcs={
    'callbacks':{
      'dragend':dragendcallback,
      'click':clickcallback
    }
  };

  /*
    Each `props` argument has had the `content` added which is used in the 
    infowindow and the callbacks are assigned. The callbacks are defined above
    but could be any of the available event type handlers in this example
    - but you could supply any function that should be called when the marker 
    is added
  */
  addMarker( Object.assign( { coordinates:{ lat: 51.506, lng: -0.188 }, content:'Kensington Palace Pavillion'}, funcs ) );
  addMarker( Object.assign( { coordinates:{ lat: 51.497, lng: -0.129 }, content:'London School of Bollywood'}, funcs ) );
  addMarker( Object.assign( { coordinates:{ lat: 51.515, lng: -0.098 }, content:'Cheapside'}, funcs ) );


  function addMarker( props ){ 
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
      position:props.coordinates,
      content:props.content,
      draggable:true,
      banana:(e)=>{ alert( 'Hello World... This function is assigned as a property of the marker and called from the `dragend` callback') },
      map:map
    });

    /*
      add all the `callback` functions if the `props` 
      arg has a `callbacks` property
    */
    if( props.hasOwnProperty('callbacks') ){
      Object.keys( props.callbacks ).forEach( type=>{
        marker.addListener( type, props.callbacks[ type ] )
      })
    }
  };
}
```

```css
#map{
  width:800px;
  height:600px;
  float:none;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap'></script>
<div id='map'></div>
```